# Can a ui component be an activator for two items? (Trying to use a v-tooltip with a v-dialog)

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a button that is the activator for a dialog in my template. But I also want to use a tooltiop with the button. (Said otherwise, when I hover over the button I'd like to see the v-tooltip and when I click the button I'd like to open the dialog.)

I've tried to use the "append" slot on the tooltip but no success. When I add the append slot, the button completely vanishes from the rendered page.

Is it even possible to use a v-tooltip with a v-dialog in veutify?

This is what I have that does not work.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<v-app>
  <v-dialog v-model="showAddPopup" persistent max-width="600px">
    <v-tooltip slot="append" bottom>

      <v-btn slot="activator" absolute fab dark left color="primary" @click="showPopup=true">
        <v-icon dark>add</v-icon>
      </v-btn>

      <span>Tooltip</span>
    </v-tooltip>

    <app-add-new-evaluator-modal @closePopup="closePopup($event)" @submit="addNewEvaluator" />
  </v-dialog>
</v-app>
```

Comment: Just use `slot="activator"` on both tooltip and btn? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yGLwYQ

Comment: Thanks a bunch, @Traxo - you were right. Simple fix that I completely missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Traxo. All I had to do was add the `slot="activator"`to both components for it to work.

Answer (score 37):

The Vuetify docs explain how to do this, but you'll find it in the Menu Component:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus#menu-with-activator-and-tooltip

Here's a simple example which opens a dialog with a button that has a tooltip:

```
<v-dialog>
  <template #activator="{ on: dialog }">
    <v-tooltip>
      <template #activator="{ on: tooltip }">
        <v-btn v-on="{ ...tooltip, ...dialog }">Button</v-btn>
      </template>
      <span>Tooltip text</span>
    </v-tooltip>
  </template>
  <v-card>
    Dialog content
  </v-card>
</v-dialog>
```

Comment: this is clearly the solution that works in all cases.

Comment: This should be the solution

Comment: Only issue I found with this approach is that once the dialog box is closed the tooltip text pops open again. Not sure how to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

⚠️ ⚠️ **problem with this solution, menu gets closed when you click anywhere on it** ⚠️ ⚠️

Use this only if you can afford it to close anywhere you click:

```
<template>
    <v-menu>
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on: menu, attrs }">
            <v-tooltip bottom>
                <template v-slot:activator="{ on: tooltip }">
                    <v-btn v-bind="attrs" v-on="{ ...tooltip, ...menu }" fab>
                        <v-icon>mdi-account-multiple-plus</v-icon>
                    </v-btn>
                </template>
                <span>tooltip</span>
            </v-tooltip>
        </template>
        <v-card>
            <v-card-title class="headline grey lighten-2">
                title
            </v-card-title>
            <v-card-text>
                text
            </v-card-text>
            <v-divider></v-divider>
            <v-card-actions>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-btn text @click="dialog = false">
                    I accept
                </v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
    </v-menu>
</template>
```